# Limiting five letter string to only include words from dictionary in Crunch?

Tags: brute-force, dictionary, crunch

I am creating a word list for attacking a personal .dmg file on OS X. I'm using John the Ripper for the cracking, and Crunch to create the word list:

```
./crunch 13 13 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 123456789\`\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\=\-\[\]\{\}\\\|\"\'\:\;\<\,\>\.\?\/ -t @@@@@%%%FOOBA -o /dictionary.txt
```

- `FOOBA`: The word that I know.
- `%%`: A combo of a letter and a special characters
- `@@@@@`: I'm 98% sure this is a five letter word. I'm positive it's an english word (in lower case).

This creates a 15GB dictionary which isn't really practical with my computer setup. To reduce the size I'd like to cross check the entries for the the first portion (`@@@@@`) against [a decent dictionary](https://www.bestwordlist.com/5letterwords.txt).

Having made the dictionary of a GAZILLION words, any thoughts about how to best remove those options not in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

It was easier to create two different lists and combined them, i think. In Python:

```
import itertools
b = ['11FOOBA', '12FOOBA', 'etc....']
a = ['aahed', 'aalii', 'aargh', 'aarti', 'etc...........']

combined = [f + l for f, l in itertools.product(a, b)]

thefile = open('test.txt', 'w')
for item in combined:
  thefile.write("%s\n" % item)

thefile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using crunch is a strange choice, and given that 15GB is too large...

John the Ripper has 'rules' for permutating on passwords.

http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I did look at John the Ripper ... as I recall it was painfully slow in comparison to other applications that you could feed dictionaries to. Perhaps I don't know how to use it - but even if forked a number of times until my computer was burning hot, it never approached a speed that could crack something in this lifetime.